# Part of one, and found in eight

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I thought of this myself, while I was trying to fall asleep, actually. It's my first one, so I hope it's alright.

> I'm part of one and found in eight.
> I have no hands, yet I create.
> I have no face, yet I have hairs.
> All of my circles are actually squares.
> I may have a stick.
> I'll save you a pic.

What am I?

#### Hint:

> The hairs and the stick are connected.

Comment: The only clue that has not yet been correctly interpreted/solved by somebody is the first line.

Comment: I have too many ideas floating around and don't want to commit to an answer. Does 8 perhaps refer to [irefvba ahzore](http://www.decode.org/?q=irefvba+ahzore)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on the answer from [Alex](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10037/alex), I believe the answer is

> Microsoft Paint

I'm part of one and found in eight.

> Paint was included in the first version of Windows, and in Windows 8

I have no hands, yet I create.

> Paint has no "hand-grabby" tool

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> The paintbrush tool

All of my circles are actually squares.

> Paint is based on pixels, not vector graphics. Everything is composed of squares.

I may have a stick.

> Paint brush

I'll save you a pic.

> Ctrl+s

Comment: That's the answer I had in mind, great job!

Answer (score 5):

> A motherboard in a computer

First of all, it's part of:

> One computer, but sometimes the same motherboard may be found in eight release versions of the computer

It has no hands and can be used to create almost anything:

> <strike>Literally</strike> computers can make *almost* anything.

It has no face, yet:

> The internal circuitry can develop hairs (called tin whiskers)

All it's circles are squares because:

> Onscreen the circles it can draw are displayed as pixels which are square

I may have a stick:

> A USB stick

I'll save you a pic:

> More like download a pic from the internet

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Are you a:

> Camera

I'm part of one and found in eight.

> *This one I don't get. Perhaps related to the exposure time like 1/8?*

I have no hands, yet I create.

> A camera creates images without having hands.

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> It may have cross hairs.

All of my circles are actually squares.

> The lens is circular but the image is square/rectangular.

I may have a stick.

> A selfie stick or camera stand.

I'll save you a pic.

> A camera saves a picture to the memory card.

Comment: Wow. Another interesting answer that I wasn't looking for. Maybe I should give another hint... I may wait a while longer first.

Answer (score 3):

are you :

> paint brush

I'm part of one and found in eight.

> Didn't figure out yet

I have no hands, yet I create.

> it doesn't have hands but it can create pictures

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> paint brush don't have face but have hairs

All of my circles are actually squares.

> no idea about this too.

I may have a stick.

> paint brush have stick to hold them

I'll save you a pic.

> as already explain.

and as hint:

> hair and stick are connected

Comment: No, but you're getting really warm!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very fragmented answer but maybe?

> Bit

Part of one, found in eight

> Eight bits in one byte

All of my circles are actually squares

> A bit is often times represented as a square that is either filled or not, so zeros (and ones) are represented as squares

I may have a stick

> "Stick" is another term for a flash memory drive, made up of bits

I'll save you a pic

> Pictures can be saved on memory, again made of bits.

Answer (score 3):

Weird answer:

> An Angle

I'm part of one and found in eight.

> 1 can have a carat at the top, so it has an angle in it.  An 8 has two angles that meet at the center, so it can be found (twice) in 8

I have no hands, yet I create.

> You can create geometric shapes with it

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> You will sometimes add hashes (hairs) onto the legs of an angle

All of my circles are actually squares.

> An angle of 360 degrees is represented by a square

I may have a stick.

> The legs (which are connected to the hairs)

I'll save you a pic.

> ... This one I have no answer for.

Comment: Carat shares the '6' key for me.

Comment: @mbomb007: I think Chelsea's talking about the angle in the number 1, not the key.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Puzzling, Chelsea! c:

Answer (score 3):

Are you:

> CorelDraw?

I'm part of one and found in eight.

> 8 version of CorelDraw in a all-in-one package

I have no hands, yet I create.

> You create many things with it

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> Hairlines for drawing

All of my circles are actually squares.

> Circle are actually controlled by a square with 9 control points

I may have a stick.

> Paint tools?

I'll save you a pic.

> For sure

Comment: Your answer is the closest so far to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @mbomb007 dang, thought of all similar softwares but none of them fits

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's another try

> A pilaster panel

They are all part of a set of eight.

It has no hands yet it creates:

> art, and all the emotions associated with the observation of art

It has no face yet it has hairs:

> The texture of the surface could be described as hairy, and the wood undoubtedly has fine hairs

All of its circles are squares:

> The border circling the artwork itself is square, and is inscribed with squares

I may have a stick:

> It's made of oak wood, and is shaped like a long rectangular stick

I'll save you a pic:

> As a piece of artwork it is regularly photographed

And for the hint:

> The hairs and the stick are one and the same, it's carved from wood

Comment: Since when does wood have fine hairs? Overall, I don't think this fits enough of the clues.

Comment: The grain of wood can be compared to hair, and weathered wood also has "hair" like fragments jutting out: http://previews.123rf.com/images/frankljunior/frankljunior1004/frankljunior100400166/6880722-Weathered-Gray-Wood-Grain-Background-Close-Up-Stock-Photo-texture.jpg, depends if you're being poetic - but I do agree, certainly not the best fit, but you never know!

Comment: Also, I hadn't heard of a pilaster panel before. The answer is something that the average user would know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's

> The letter e

I am part of one and found in eight

> Both words contain the letter

I have no hands, yet I create.

> Letter is not found in hands but it is in create

I have no face, yet I have hairs.

> Metaphor for the leg part of the lower case letter e

All of my circles are actually squares.

> Visual metaphor for describing the difference between upper case E and lower case E

I may have a stick.

> The leg thing again

I'll save you a pic.

> Maybe a keyboard shortcut, unsure on this one

Comment: No. The "letter e" riddle is a separate riddle, and again, it doesn't definitively fit the clues. It may even have been done before on this site, not sure.

Comment: @mbomb007 There can be multiple riddles with the same answer.

Comment: Sure, but if I'm going to spend my time making a riddle, it's going to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Hair brush

6.

> Usually we prefer to use a  hair brush before a pic is taken

5.

> Hair brush has a handle to hold

4.

> Hair brush has groups of bristles which actually look like squares

3.

> hair brush has bristles which means hair

2.

> Hair brush can be used to by hair dresses to create new designs

1. > Not sure

Comment: Not what I'm looking for.